# Simplifying the expectation of an exponent

Tags: probability, expectation

Although the steps seem short, it is not clear to me how the underlined expression in the figure below was gotten. Any hint(s) that could help?

Because $\text g \sim exp (1)$, the expectation term is obtained as

[image: this] 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need three facts. Suppose $X \sim \text{Exponential}(\lambda)$ (where $\mathbb{E}[X] = \dfrac{1}{\lambda}$), $\lambda \neq 0$.

(1) For $x \geq 0$, $\mathbb{P}(X \leq x) = 1-e^{-\lambda x}\text{.}$

*Proof*. 
$$\mathbb{P}(X \leq x) = \int_{0}^{x}\lambda e^{-\lambda t}\text{ d}t = -[e^{-\lambda t}]^{x}_{0}=1-e^{-\lambda x}\text{.}$$

(2) For $x \geq 0$, $\mathbb{P}(X > x) = e^{-\lambda x}$

*Proof*. $$\mathbb{P}(X > x) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(X \leq x) = 1 - (1-e^{-\lambda x}) = e^{-\lambda x}\text{.}\tag{*}$$

Also, don't forget that

$$\mathbb{P}(X > x) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(X \leq x) = \int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda e^{-\lambda t}\text{ d}t-\int_{0}^{x}\lambda e^{-\lambda t}\text{ d}t=\int_{x}^{\infty}\lambda e^{-\lambda t}\text{ d}t\tag{**}$$
which must equal $e^{-\lambda x}$ by (*).

(3) It follows from the above that since
$$\int_{0}^{x}\lambda e^{-\lambda t}\text{ d}t = \lambda \int_{0}^{x}e^{-\lambda t}\text{ d}t = 1 - e^{-\lambda x}$$
that
$$\int_{0}^{x}e^{-\lambda t} \text{ d}t = \dfrac{1-e^{-\lambda x}}{\lambda}\text{.}\tag{***}$$

---

Thus, we have from (***) that

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\chi P_c^{-1}\|x_i\|^{\alpha}}e^{-sP_cg_i\|x_i\|^{-\alpha}}e^{-g_i}\text{ d}g_i &= \int_{0}^{\chi P_c^{-1}\|x_i\|^{\alpha}}e^{-[sP_cg_i\|x_i\|^{-\alpha}+g_i]}\text{ d}g_i \\
&= \int_{0}^{\chi P_c^{-1}\|x_i\|^{\alpha}}e^{-g_i[sP_c\|x_i\|^{-\alpha}+1]}\text{ d}g_i \\
&= \dfrac{1-e^{-[sP_c\|x_i\|^{-\alpha}+1][\chi P_c^{-1}\|x_i\|^{\alpha}]}}{sP_c\|x_i\|^{-\alpha}+1} \\
&= \dfrac{1-e^{-[s\chi P_c^{-1}P_c\|x_i\|^{-\alpha}\|x_i\|^{\alpha}+\chi P_c^{-1}\|x_i\|^{\alpha}]}}{sP_c\|x_i\|^{-\alpha}+1} \\
&= \dfrac{1-e^{-[s\chi +\chi P_c^{-1}\|x_i\|^{\alpha}]}}{sP_c\|x_i\|^{-\alpha}+1}
\end{align}$$
Furthermore, from (*) and (**), we have
$$\int_{\chi P_c^{-1}\|x_i\|^{\alpha}}^{\infty}e^{-g_i}\text{ d}g_i = e^{-(1)[\chi P_c^{-1}\|x_i\|^{\alpha}]} = e^{-\chi P_c^{-1}\|x_i\|^{\alpha}}\text{.}$$
Note that this integral is based on $\lambda = 1$.

Comment: Brilliant answer! Your answer is well expressed, well conveyed and well received. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Collecting the exponents we can rewrite the integral in the first line to get $\int^{\chi P^{-1}_c ||x_i ||^\alpha}_0 e^{-(sP_c||x_i||^{-\alpha}+1)g_i}dg_i +\int^\infty _{\chi P^{-1}_c ||x_i ||^\alpha} e^{-g_i} dg_i$ now, as you will know $\int^a _b e^{cx} dx = \frac{e^{ca} -e^{cb}}{c}$, and applying this to your integrals and using $e^0 =1$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{-x}/x = 0$  we get $ -\frac{e^{-sP_c||x_i||^{-\alpha}+1)\chi P^{-1}_c ||x_i ||^\alpha}-1}{sP_c||x_i||^{-\alpha}+1} + {e^{-{\chi P^{-1}_c ||x_i ||^\alpha}}}$ multiplying out the exponent in the first term we get $ -\frac{e^{-(s\chi+\chi P^{-1}_c ||x_i ||^\alpha)}-1}{sP_c||x_i||^{-\alpha}+1} + {e^{-{\chi P^{-1}_c ||x_i ||^\alpha}}}$  which you can clearly see is equal to $ \frac{1-e^{-(s\chi+\chi P^{-1}_c ||x_i ||^\alpha})}{sP_c||x_i||^{-\alpha}+1} + {e^{-{\chi P^{-1}_c ||x_i ||^\alpha}}}$ and we're done.

edit: I've just seen Clarinetist's answer and it's probably a bit clearer than mine.

Comment: +1 For also providing an alternate approach to the answer! Thanks!